# Atheros card not functioning well under WPA2

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, network-adapter

I've got a Toshiba Satellite L25-S199, and it includes an Atheros wireless NIC based on the `AR2413` chipset, I believe. Currently I'm running OpenSUSE 11.4 on it, but I've previously had Xubuntu and Ubuntu, and this problem has always existed with WPA2.

Specifically, the LAN is a wireless WPA2 with AES encryption (no TKIP). The computer can connect to the network just fine, but the web is all but unusable; it is very finicky, mostly failing to fetch any pages, but sometimes succeeding (mostly with Google pages, and those from the local network's servers). Perhaps a DNS issue?

This problem doesn't occur with WEP or no encryption.

Here's the output of `lspci`

```
09:04.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR2413 802.11bg NIC (rev 01)
```

And the relevant output of `hwinfo`

```
22: PCI 904.0: 0282 WLAN controller
  [Created at pci.318]
  Unique ID: y9sn.SufKn0XT2bB
  Parent ID: qscc.hTSZxA6Z5F6
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.4/0000:09:04.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:09:04.0
  Hardware Class: network
  Model: "Atheros AR2413 802.11bg NIC"
  Vendor: pci 0x168c "Atheros Communications Inc."
  Device: pci 0x001a "AR2413 802.11bg NIC"
  SubVendor: pci 0x144f "Askey Computer Corp."
  SubDevice: pci 0x7094 
  Revision: 0x01
  Driver: "ath5k"
  Driver Modules: "ath5k"
  Device File: wlan0
  Features: WLAN
  Memory Range: 0xc0200000-0xc020ffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 22 (80837 events)
  HW Address: 00:11:f5:84:2d:c4
  Link detected: yes
  WLAN channels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
  WLAN frequencies: 2.412 2.417 2.422 2.427 2.432 2.437 2.442 2.447 2.452 2.457 2.462
  WLAN encryption modes: WEP40 WEP104 TKIP CCMP
  WLAN authentication modes: open sharedkey wpa-psk wpa-eap
  Module Alias: "pci:v0000168Cd0000001Asv0000144Fsd00007094bc02sc00i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: ath5k is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe ath5k"
  Config Status: cfg=no, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #16 (PCI bridge)
```

Comment: `lspci -s 09:04`

Answer (score 0):

What are you connecting to?   My own router (DIR-655) drops out under high WPA2 traffic loads (three computers in house, shuffling gigabytes of data between systems, all internal)

Dropping encryption to WEP resolves my issues, but while I've cracked all my neighbor's WEP codes, I'd prefer WPA2 (if only to make it challenging!).

From your description, it doesn't sound like a problem with your laptop at all.  Have you (I hate this!) rebooted your router?  Your DSL modem or CABLE modem?  Does this slowness afflict other systems?

Also check your DNS settings, a faulty or slow DNS can severely affect your internet experience.  I'd drop mine here, but Google around for some. (No, I won't recommend opendns either!)

Comment: I'm almost positive that it has nothing to do with my router. This is a fairly old laptop (Celeron M) and has had issues for one reason or another. Since I posted this, I've tried installing other distros for better compatibility (the X server on OpenSUSE started failing for some reason) and am now using Lubuntu (fairly successfully!). I have a USB wifi card that I'm using, and it is working with WPA2. So, I think the issue is with the internal NIC itself (and I would still like to know why). Plus, there are many other computers on the network, and they are all fine with the WPA2 encryption.